# Expand/collapse all accordions

Tags: javascript, angular, accordion

I am trying to create an accordion, where you can click on each accordion, but I would also like to have another button where a click expands or collapses all accordions.

So right now I have this `.ts` component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-faq',
  templateUrl: './faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./faq.component.scss'],

})
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {

  accordion1: boolean;
  accordion2: boolean;
  accordion3: boolean;
  accordionAll: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Now, each accordion is just some CSS, and then I can activate each one with:

```
<div class="accordion-header" (click)="accordion1 = !accordion1" [ngClass]="accordion1 ? 'is-active' : ''">Accordion 1</div>
```

And then I can give it some styling and activate some accordion content with that particular `accordion1` state.

For the expand/collapse all I currently have something like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!accordionAll" (click)="accordion1 = true; accordion2 = true; accordion3 = true; accordionAll = true"></div>
<div *ngIf="accordionAll" (click)="accordion1 = false; accordion2 = false; accordion3 = false; accordionAll = false"></div>
```

Now, in some sense this works. But if I suddenly have 20 different accordions, this will be horrendeus. Also, I don't like that I need to have two divs, since some kind of animation (of e.g. an icon) doesn't work that well this way.

So my question is: How do I do this the "right" way, where it doesn't get a mess with many accordions, and where I can actually do the expand/collapse all with only one button ?

Comment: You can use ngClass instead of using two-element for both toggled or not state.
`<div *ngIf="!accordionAll" (click)="toogleAll(!accordionAll)" [ngClass]="{ activated:  accordionAll }"></div>`
And give some animation with additional `activated` class.

Comment: You really should use classes, it will lessen your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're traking the state of `accordionAll` already, you don't need to pass a boolean to a method.

```html
<div (click)="toggleAll()"></div>
```

```js
toggleAll(): void { 
  this.accordionAll = !this.accordionAll
  this.accordion1 = this.accordionAll;
  this.accordion2 = this.accordionAll;
  this.accordion3 = this.accordionAll
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I Think that something like this gonna work.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-faq',
  templateUrl: './faq.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./faq.component.scss'],

})
export class FaqComponent implements OnInit {

  accordion1: boolean;
  accordion2: boolean;
  accordion3: boolean;
  accordionAll: boolean;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toogleAll() {
     this.accordion1 = this.accordionAll;
     this.accordion2 = this.accordionAll;
     this.accordion3 = this.accordionAll;

     this.accordionAll = !this.accordionAll;
  }

}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="!accordionAll" (click)="toogleAll()"></div>
<div *ngIf="accordionAll" (click)="toogleAll()"></div>
```